# Execute Command on Login in Fedora 16

Tags: linux

I want to execute this code on every login:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

I tried to put this command into ~/.xsession or ~/.xinitrc but that doesn't work for me. In which file do I have to put this command?

I am using Gnome with Fedora 16.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does it work if you just type it in the terminal?

Comment: yes, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=xmodmap
Exec=xmodmap -e 'Clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

GNOME should then run that command on all subsequent logins.

Comment: with the line

    Type=Application

it works. Thank you!

Comment: @its-me:  Sorry about that; I'll fix it for future readers.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Since your using GNOME your probably using GDM and alternatively you can use

`/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`

see [here](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en) for details